# Comparators in Object2Vec

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

Currently, Object2Vec supports these [comparators](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/object2vec-hyperparameters.html): "hadamard, concat, abs_diff". I am trying to build a user-item recommendation system. I am wondering which comparator to pick for this particular use case. I would love to learn more about the effect of comparators in general.